# Azure Data Factory Blob Event Trigger not working

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

We see below error message for ADF Blob Event Trigger and there was no code change for Blob trigger container, folder path. We see this error for Web Activity, when included into pipeline.

```
ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression '*sanitized*'
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add the error screenshot?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, please find screenshot

Comment: Could you please clarify what does this mean *sanitized* in your trigger?

Comment: This error is thrown when user configuration issue happens and generic code handler is triggered from Azure ADF side

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and fixed it. Here is the solution

The problem is that I parameterised some input for linkedService and datasets. For example, here is one of my blob storage datasets `Bicep` file

```
    resource stagingBlobDataset 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets@2018-06-01' = {
      // ... Create a JSON file dataset in a blob storage linkedService 
      parameters: {
        tableName: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      }
      typeProperties: {
        location: {
          type: 'AzureBlobStorageLocation'
          // fileName: '@concat(dataset().tableName,\'.json\')' // WRONG LINE
          // new line  
          fileName: { 
            value: '@concat(dataset().tableName,\'.json\')'
            type: 'Expression'
          }
          }
        }
      }
    }


I hope that Microsoft has provided more info. Anyway, I found the issue in my Data Factory code
```

Comment: I got clarification from MS- this is user configuration issue, whenever system does not get exact cause, it will show above error.